# Implementation binary tree by C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I`m trying to create a binary tree by c++.
'init_tree' function read cin and use these characters to build a tree. But seems that this function is useless.
Could anybody tell me where is the mistake and how to fix it?

```
#ifndef STUDY_TREE_H
#define STUDY_TREE_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
    char data;
    Node *l_child, *r_child;
};
void init_tree(Node* node) {
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == '#') {
        node = NULL;
    } else {
        node = new Node;
        std::cout << ch << std::endl;
        node->data = ch;
        init_tree(node->l_child);
        init_tree(node->r_child);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Input tree, eg: ABC#D" << std::endl;
    Node *root = NULL;
    init_tree(root);
    return 0;
}
#endif //STUDY_TREE_H
```

Comment: What happens when the read fails? `cin >> ch` will fail when it runs out nodes especially if `ABC#D` is the only input. If your code is going to give examples it should be complete and valid examples. `AB##C#D##`

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying a copy of the pointer, and not the actual pointer. Use a reference.

```cpp
void init_tree(Node*& node)
```